# Android DatePicker updateDate from Date

Tags: android, datepicker

all.
I have some problem with updating value of DatePicker from my variable.

So, first what I did - create DatePicker and get Date from it

```
    final DatePicker newDatePicker = (DatePicker)view.findViewById(R.id.dpResult);
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    newDatePicker.init(year, month, day, null);
    newDatePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Date date = new Date(newDatePicker.getYear()-1900, 
                                  newDatePicker.getMonth(), 
                                  newDatePicker.getDayOfMonth());
            //hear is some list where I add the date field
            dealList.add(new ItemDeal(newDescription.getText().toString(), date,
                        false));
            ((BaseAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Then when I want to edit some information I want that DatePicker show the date from this field. So I tried to use DatePicker.updateDate():

```
    final DatePicker newDatePicker = (DatePicker)view.findViewById(R.id.dpResult);

    Date itemDate = (Date)c.dealList.get(numberOfItem).getDealTime();

    //newDatePicker.init(itemDate.getYear(), itemDate.getMonth(), itemDate.getMonth(), null);
    newDatePicker.updateDate(itemDate.getYear(), itemDate.getMonth(), itemDate.getMonth());
```

When I did so, the DatePicker showed 01 Jan 1900.  Through debugger i saw itemDate - it had the Date.
Please help. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you doing this newDatePicker.getYear()-1900 and this  newDatePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);? I think you don't need those.

EDIT: Try to write out to System.err date that you formed, i think it is not right, and watch log cat output. Post output here.

Comment: newDatePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000) - without this program doesn't work. Because you can set calendar only the previous date(for example - a second before). I read some article on stackoverflow. But for 1900 your are right. It is something strange about DatePicker. When I get date from it and then  attach to textView it gives values currentYear+1900. So it was my mistake, when i updated DatePicker - the year was to small. Now it's working OK!

Comment: Log cat is nice way to quickly debug stuff, i use it all the time. Good think i helped :D

Comment: @DjDexter5GHz Thanks for the solution. `datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);` did the trick for me.